# Compare two dates in Angular

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, date-comparison

I want to compare two dates. I'm new in Angular

The two dates are in same format mm/dd/yyyy

```
  <pre>{{CurrentDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</pre>
  <pre>{{cmp_actl_del_date }}</pre>
```

these three are my dates. I want to check cmp_actl_del_date > the current date.

Comment: Check out this:
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707377/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-angularjs** Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses objects to store date values. When you want to compare if two dates are equal don't do this like `date1 === date2`. That will just tell you if the two variables reference the same object.

To check if two dates are equal use the getTime() method of the date object. Like this:

```
date1.getTime() == date2.getTime()
```

Be careful because any difference in seconds will fail to match the dates.

Now `ng-if` will accept AngularJS expressions. 
Ensure that both variables are valid JavaScript date objects.

I recommend that you use the moment javascript library for date processing. It makes working with dates a lot easier.